# Getting contents of an address in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

Is it possible in C++ to get the contents of an address in memory if I don't have a pointer to it, but I do have the address itself as a `uint_32`?

Thanks

EDIT

I am writing to those locations, and was trying to see if my write() function was working properly, so I wanted to manually do a read from the addresses. The 'contents' mentioned above are of type `uint64_t` and this is what I've tried doing, but this gives me a `Segmentation Fault`.

```
uint64_t *contents = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(start_address);
cout<< hex << "Contents: " << *contents << endl;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you'll need to give more context on what you're situation is / what you're trying to accomplish in order to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Unsure of portability, but you can use `reinterpret_cast<>`. e.g.

```
uint_32 adrs;
int *p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(adrs);  // int* should be 32-bit for portable code
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (please see EDIT in question), but for some reason I keep getting a segmentation fault. Why does that happen?

Comment: @zohair, then there is a possibility that pointer data is not stored in `uint_64` properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if the address is in your [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) (or if you are running on a microcontroller or in kernel space). Otherwise it will cause a seg fault.

Simply cast the uint_32 to an int pointer, and dereference it:

```
int contents = *((int*)uintAddress);
```

Comment: You should use reinterpret_cast<> instead of the C-style cast (noting the C++ tag, rather than the C tag).

Comment: What are the advantages of that over C-style casting?

Comment: C-style casts can cast away const-ness, whereas reinterpret_cast<> & static_cast<> can't (not that it's relevant to your answer, but just know that C-style cast is more dangerous than reinterpret_cast<>).

Comment: @Chriszuma: In this case, it just makes it more clear that you're doing something odd. More generally, C++ casts allow you to restrict the types of conversions that are possible (e.g. preserving `const` qualifiers, or preventing conversions between unrelated class types), making it easier to catch errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, if you cast this integer to a pointer:

```
SomeData value = *reinterpret_cast<SomeData*>(some_int);
```

But you have to be 100% sure that your integer really *is* an address, or bad things are likely to happen. So this is considered bad practice and usually a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You just cast it to pointer and dereference.

Answer (score 0):

C-style variant:

```
uint_32 x = 0xc0de;
int *addr = (int*)x;
printf("Address %d contains %d", x, *addr);
```

Comment: this will likely cause some segmentation fault on 32 bit protected mode architectures whose "negative addresses" are reserved by the kernel.

Comment: Absolutely. Btw, 'negative addresses' IMO is incorrect definition.